# Count how many months has passed since

Tags: php, date

I'm using numerals for each month. If I want to know how many months have passed since 5 (last May), how would I go about that?

```
$current_month = date('m');
$other_month = 5;
$months_since = ?;
```

So some results would be like:

**Example 1:**

```
$current_month = 3
$other_month = 1 
$months_since = 3
```

**Example 2:**

```
$current_month = 3 
$other_month = 9 
$months_since = 7
```

Comment: Please post what you have already tried and where are you facing issues?

Comment: What I attempted was drastically wrong, so I didn't include it. But if you really need to know: $months_since = $current_month + $other_month;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/765065)

```
$current_month = 3;
$other_month = 10;
if($current_month>=$other_month)
{
    echo $current_month-$other_month+1;
}
else
{
    echo (12-$other_month)+$current_month+1;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As your logic, you can use this code:

```
$months_since = $current_month - $other_month + 1;
```